# redirect to 404 page

Tags: redirect, 404-error

I am using kadence free theme, and I need to get rid of some of my pages.

However because they are already indexed I can't simply delete them. so, i was thinking of doing a 404 redirect.

so, the idea is that I have another domain,where I will do 301 redirect from the pages that are the same and from the posts as well.

But form a few other pages that are useless, I need to find a way to do 404 redirect?

So, I was working with redirections plugin, but it only does 301 redirect turns out, can anyone please help me do this or suggest another free plugin

Comment: 404 is NOT a redirect, it's a status code that must not change the URL.

Comment: I’m not up on SEO but if you have deleted content then the 404 you’ll get from deleting the page is correct isn’t it? Or maybe 410 Gone instead?

Answer (score 0):

Almost every hosting provider provide this redirection feature in their admin panel, so you can redirect from there.

Alternatively, you can use [Page Links To](https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-links-to/) plugin.

Comment: Yes, 404 is not a redirect. So, I created a dummy 404 page and 301 redirected those pages that I don't need with a few exceptions of sending them to the home page. Hope it will be fine.

Thank you guys for your responses though